# Dataframe: Using "Name" Column as Segmentation, Get all dates between Startdate and Enddate columns While Excluding Weekend Dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, group-by

Let's say I have the starting input table below.

| Name | _leavestartdate | _leaveenddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jerry Rice | 2023-12-26 | 2023-12-26 |
| Pablo Picasso | 2023-08-15 | 2023-08-21 |
| Ray Ramon | 2023-03-16 | 2023-03-17 |

The Python code to create it is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["Jerry Rice","Pablo Picasso","Ray Ramon"],'_leavestartdate':["2023-12-26","2023-08-15","2023-03-16"],'_leaveenddate':["2023-12-26","2023-08-21","2023-03-17"]})
```

First, I want to get all dates between the _leavestartdate and _leaveenddate **split based on Name column**.  The list of dates would populate under new column "Date".  I also want to exclude **any weekend dates** in the newly reformatted table.

So my desired output table is shown below.  Note that it only shows weekday dates and excludes the 2 dates (8/19/2023 and 8/20/2023) from Pablo Picasso that are weekend dates.

| Name | Date | _leavestartdate | _leaveenddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jerry Rice | 2023-12-26 | 2023-12-26 | 2023-12-26 |
| Pablo Picasso | 2023-08-15 | 2023-08-15 | 2023-08-21 |
| Pablo Picasso | 2023-08-16 | 2023-08-15 | 2023-08-21 |
| Pablo Picasso | 2023-08-17 | 2023-08-15 | 2023-08-21 |
| Pablo Picasso | 2023-08-18 | 2023-08-15 | 2023-08-21 |
| Pablo Picasso | 2023-08-21 | 2023-08-15 | 2023-08-21 |
| Ray Ramon | 2023-03-16 | 2023-03-16 | 2023-03-17 |
| Ray Ramon | 2023-03-17 | 2023-03-16 | 2023-03-17 |

I looked at previous solutions in StackOverflow and tried the following code:

```
date = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=df.min()._leavestartdate, 
                     end=df.max()._leaveenddate), columns=['Date'])

df_final = pd.merge(left=date, right=df, left_on='Date', right_on='_leavestartdate', 
         how='outer').fillna(method='ffill')
```

But the solution produces the following wrong table because it's not accounting for the "Name" column:

[image]

How can I fix the code to get my desired output table?

Comment: One way of doing this is to do a `cross join` between `date` and `df` then filter to return only rows where `Date` is `>=_leavestartdate` and `<=_leaveendddate`. Not sure the exact syntax off the top of my head and it's not very efficient in the tables are large.

Comment: Filtering your result with this condition may be sufficient.

Comment: @David: Do you mean filter "Date" column so that it is within the startdate and enddate columns?  But I think this would still have the weekend dates included ... which I probably could flag in a different column and drop them.

Comment: Yeah you can add an additional criteria to the filter, you should be able to use df['Date'].dt.day_name() to do the weekend filtering (using `isin()` to check if it's in Saturday/Sunday).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df['_leavestartdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_leavestartdate'])
df['_leaveenddate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_leaveenddate'])


df_final = pd.concat([(pd.DataFrame({'Date':
                             pd.date_range(df.loc[i, '_leavestartdate'],
                                           df.loc[i, '_leaveenddate']),
                                     'name': df.loc[i, 'name']}))
                      for i in range(len(df))])

df_final = df_final[df_final['Date'].dt.dayofweek < 5]


print(df_final.merge(df, how='left', on='name'))
```

Here, in the list comprehension, the necessary rows of dataframes are generated and concatenate. Then the lines with Saturday and Sunday were removed and a left-hand merge was made by name.

You can even do without a merge and write _leavestartdate, _leaveenddate in df_final:

```
df_final = pd.concat([(pd.DataFrame({'Date':
                                         pd.date_range(df.loc[i, '_leavestartdate'],
                                                       df.loc[i, '_leaveenddate']),
                                     'name': df.loc[i, 'name'],
                                     '_leavestartdate': df.loc[i, '_leavestartdate'],
                                     '_leaveenddate': df.loc[i, '_leaveenddate']}))
                      for i in range(len(df))])

df_final = df_final[df_final['Date'].dt.dayofweek < 5]
```

Output

```
        Date           name _leavestartdate _leaveenddate
0 2023-12-26     Jerry Rice      2023-12-26    2023-12-26
1 2023-08-15  Pablo Picasso      2023-08-15    2023-08-21
2 2023-08-16  Pablo Picasso      2023-08-15    2023-08-21
3 2023-08-17  Pablo Picasso      2023-08-15    2023-08-21
4 2023-08-18  Pablo Picasso      2023-08-15    2023-08-21
5 2023-08-21  Pablo Picasso      2023-08-15    2023-08-21
6 2023-03-16      Ray Ramon      2023-03-16    2023-03-17
7 2023-03-17      Ray Ramon      2023-03-16    2023-03-17
```

If I didn’t take into account anything, please write.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you :)